# Windows Azure is Undefined JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, azure

I'am developing a phonegap application for Windows Phone 8 (Javascript +HTML5) (Cordova 2.8.1) and I want to use Azure mobileservice as a database for my app but an error is occuring in this instruction `var MobileServiceClient = WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient("...","...");` can you please tell me what is wrong?

I call these script :

```
type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'
type="text/javascript" src='https://partnergymservice.azure-mobile.net/client/MobileServices.Web-1.0.0.min.js'
type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"
```

and this my script file :

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


function onDeviceReady() {

                try
                {

                    var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(
         ".....",
         "......");


                }
                catch (err) {
                    element.innerHTML = err.message;
                }
```

Comment: What is the error? Maybe try `WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Azure Mobile Services SDK.

This is outlined in [Step 4 of the "Getting Started" tutorial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-data-js/#update-app).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GWT you need to use $wnd in front of WindowsAzure as below:

```
var client = new $wnd.WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(
        "https://xxxxx.azure-mobile.net/",
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    );
```